# How do I work with an internal JSON in my project with Swift?

Tags: ios, json, swift, alamofire

I have a project that converts currencies using an API that I connect with Alamofire but I want to work without Internet connection and I have downloaded the JSON that returns the API but I do not know how to work with him when I add to the project with Alamofi Re or in some other way.

Could you tell me some simple way (or not) with examples?

Thank you.

Comment: Why would you still want to use Alamofire if you have a local file?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need Alamofire if you have local json file, because Alamofire is a networking framework.
You can use Apple's Codable protocols to parse or create json (or any other external representation for that matter).
For more information about this, please read the official documentation:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/codable

The documentation also refers to an article about encoding and decoding custom types.